# Android Cast - Media Router callback not returning

Tags: android, casting, chromecast, mediarouter

I'm trying to auto discover Cast devices. This is basically verbatim what I've seen for how to do this, however I never get the callback for either onRouteAdded or onRouteSelected.

I've tried changing which flags are used, but didn't get different results. Sometimes the route will be added, but never selected.

```
private void startSearchForDevicesAndCast() {
    MediaRouter router = MediaRouter.getInstance(this);

    int count = router.getRoutes().size();

    List<MediaRouter.RouteInfo> j = router.getRoutes();
    MediaRouteSelector selector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder().addControlCategory(
            CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(getString(R.string.app_id))).build();

    router.addCallback(selector, new MediaRouter.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onRouteAdded(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
            super.onRouteAdded(router, route);
            Log.i(TAG, "onRouteAdded: ");
            router.selectRoute(route);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteChanged(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
            super.onRouteChanged(router, route);
            Log.i(TAG, "onRouteChanged: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onRouteSelected: ");
            super.onRouteSelected(router, route);
        }
    }, MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_PERFORM_ACTIVE_SCAN);
}
```

Comment: what action are you taking that you expect the onRouteSelected( to be called and it is not happening?

Comment: @AliNaddaf sorry, worded my question wrong. I was mistaken and did not get the callback for either the onRouteAdded or the onRouteSelected. Sometimes the onRouteChanged returns, but I think that is only because it's already in the route list from previous times, but the route never appears to change either. But I do see the callback for it.

Comment: Ok, let me write up the steps; since it is a bit longer, I am going to write it as an answer and not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I believe in your case, you would need to do a little bit more. Depending on the setup and structure of your app and some other factors, the route you are expecting may have already been discovered by the MediaRouter. In that case, you will not get an onRouteAdded() since it is already there. To accommodate this, one approach is after calling  `router.addCallback(..)` (as you are already doing), get the list of all present routes by calling `mMediaRouter.getRoutes()` and then filter the list for the app id that you are interested in (by using the same selector that you have defined and using `route.matchesSelector(selector)`) and consider that as your initial set of discovered devices. From that point on, the `onRouteAdded()` and `onRouteRemoved()` can be used to update the list. As for `onRouteChanged()`, that sometimes has valuable information; for example when a cast device is rebooted, and when it comes up, at the very beginning it may not have the right configuration but soon after it gets its configuration and updates certain fields and then `onRouteChanged()` is called but in most cases, you may ignore that and just focus on the initial set and the ones that get added or removed. If you want to see how this can be put together, note that what I outlined above is very close to what the MediaRouterChooserDialog does internally and since the source to that is openly available in Media Router v7 support library, you can take a look and see how it can be done.